# How do I send data between two computers over the internet

Tags: java, sockets

I have been struggling with this for the entire day now, I hope somebody can help me with this.

My problem is fairly simple: I wish to transfer data (mostly simple commands) from one PC to another over the internet.

I have been able to achieve this using sockets in Java when both computers are connected to my home router. I then connected both computers to the internet using two different mobile phones and attempted to transmit the data again. I used the mobile phones as this provides a direct route to the internet and if I use my router I have to set up port forwarding, at least, that is how I understand it.

I think the problem lies in the method that I set up the client socket. I used:

```
Socket kkSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, 3333);
```

where ipAddress is the IP address of the computer running the server. I got the IP address by right-clicking on the connection, status, support. Is that the correct IP address to use or where can I obtain the address of the server? Also, is it possible to get a fixed name for my computer that I can use instead of entering the IP address, as this changes every time I connect to the internet using my mobile phone?

Alternatively, are there better methods to solving my problem such as using http, and if so, where can I find more information about this?

**EDIT:**
Would it be possible to have the server program running on a server on the internet somewhere. My original server would then be a client that send information to this server. This server would then pass this information to my original client and vice versa. That way, the IP address of my computer won't matter, as I only need to know the address of the server hosted somewhere on the web. Does this seem like a better solution? Where do I begin implementing such a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has more to do with management of internet protocols and communications settings rather than programming. It would be better asked at ServerFault.com. Btw, your problem is multi-layered. It's fairly easy to get going on a home or even company network but when you get into the wild you have to account for firewalls, DNS, ISPs (which often do not allow server traffic) etc. If you want to code at the socket level, you will definitely have to learn TCP/IP inside out. No escaping it.

Comment: Regarding the strategy discussed in your edit.  There's a dead-easy way to get started: [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/).  You have to learned a tiny bit about servlets and a tiny bit about Google-specific data stores, but total work should be less than an hour.

Comment: @Malvolio. Thanks, that sounds like a great idea. Would it be much more difficult if I create my own server that does this than using the google app engine?

Comment: The issue is, you need to find a host.  You have to find somebody with a data center who will let you use a computer.  There are a lot of commercial outfits out there who will do it for money, there are even some other (partially) free ones, including [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/), you could even set up your own data center, with just a static IP and an unused Linux box.  GAE is just the easiest, about an hour's work.  On AWS's free-tier Beanstalk service, probably two hours.  Those are the only ones I've tried myself this month, but the others would probably be comparable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you connected to the server that serves StackOverflow, did you type in the IP address?  It's 64.34.119.12, if that jogs your memory.

You probably didn't.  You probably typed "stackoverflow.com".  There's a huge, complex, clever, and [in some ways](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Massive-DNS-security-problem-endangers-the-internet-736419.html), poorly implemented system called [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) that translates sensible and human-readable names into IP addresses.

One problem with DNS, though, is you need a "static IP", which is exactly what it sounds like: an IP address that doesn't change, which is exactly what you don't have.

So, what can you do?

1. You can buy a static IP account from your ISP (pretty expensive)
2. You can use some proxy out in the Internet (a machine that *does* have a static IP and is willing to bounce your packets back and forth -- I'm not aware of any service* that does this for you; you could write one and put it up on Amazon Web Services or Google App Engine, both of which would be free at your level of usage, but they'd be slow, since every packet trying to cross your living room would have have to go via some data-center in Virginia).
3. You can keep doing what you're doing, looking in the net-configuration of your machine.
4. You could speed (3) up a little by having your server program look up its own IP address and print it out where you could see it and type it into the server by hand.
5. You can use DynDNS, as Sergey mentioned (this is the "right" solution, in that it's very general, it just might be a little complicated to set up)
6. You can use [multi-casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast).

Multi-casting is an interesting solution, and it may work for you.  The idea is, when your server starts up, it announces to the net, "Here I am, I'm providing X server, here's my IP address, talk to me."  The problem is, a multi-cast won't leave your living room.  Obviously, if every multi-cast were spread to every computer on the Internet, the whole thing would collapse, so your router will ignore, and not route, multi-cast packets.  That may or may not be a deal-breaker for you.  **EDIT** Re-reading your question, I see it *is* a deal-breaker for you.  I'd go with #5, but be aware there may be routing issues (address translations that prevent a server from knowing the address that other computers can find it at) or fire-wall issues (that is, your ISP may prevent your server from receiving incoming packets even if the address is correct).

* in the dozen odd years since I wrote this reply, several such services have arisen, including Ngrok, Localtunnel, Serveo, Teleconsole, and Pagekite.

Comment: It depends on the ISP how expensive a static IP address is. I have two connections from different ISPs, one with static IP for about $2/month, another one with semi-static IP for free. "Semi-static" means it isn't guaranteed to be static, but only really changes when there are serious changes in the ISP software/hardware, and last time it happened a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

using a direct socket connection with a port like 3333 is usually complicated because different network configurations.

firewalls will make a pleasure preventing the connection, or killing it from time to time.

maintaining a 2-way connection can be a nighmare. the SIP protocol is struggling with this kind of problems.

For a simple application, i suggest you look into the [comet technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), where your clients can establish an http connection with a shared server. The server can then bridge commands between them.

html5 will also bring the [websocket protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) to the table.

Comment: Thanks, comet technology sounds like an interesting approach. I think I'll take a look at that.

Comment: if you don't mind my saying so, the COMET approach is a subset of the more general solution of using an open proxy, and an unnecessarily complicated one.  COMET is great if you are stuck in a browser and *must* tunnel through HTTP, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: @Malvolio - you are right i restricted the problem to a browser based question.

Answer (score 1):

> I got the IP address by right-clicking
>   on the connection, status, support.

Not sure about the "support" part, and I'm not on a Windows machine right now, but I think that the most easy and reliable way to figure out the IP address on Windows is to run "ipconfig" from the command line (Win+R, type "cmd", then "ipconfig" in the opened window). This, of course, should be done on the server side.

However, the problem is that depending on the ISP your IP address may be not within the Internet, but within a local ISP network (so-called NAT). In this case, you'll need to use some sort of black magic called [TCP hole punching](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/), which is very complicated and not guaranteed to work. You can figure out if your address is local or not by looking at it. For IPv4 local addresses are almost always like 10.x.x.x or 172.16-31.x.x, or 192.168.x.x. Don't know about IPv6.

You can also check your IP by visiting one of the special sites like [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/). If the address they tell you is different from the one you see by running "ipconfig" or looking at the connection properties, then you're almost certainly behind a NAT (or your ISP is using a transparent proxy, but that's rare).

If you are directly connected to Internet (no local addresses and NAT), then you should also check if you have any firewall software and either to configure it to allow connections to the port you use, or make sure it's in "ask the user" (and not "silently reject") mode, or just disable it completely (this may put your computer at risk, especially if there is no anti-virus software or the system isn't up-to-date).

> Also, is it possible to get a fixed
>   name for my computer that I can use
>   instead of entering the IP address, as
>   this changes every time I connect to
>   the internet using my mobile phone?

Yes, it's possible. There is the thing called DynDNS, and there are DynDNS providers like [DynDNS.com](http://www.dyndns.com/), where you can get a third-level domain name for free (like mycoolpc.dyndns.org). You'll have to install and configure some DynDNS client on your PC that will tell the DynDNS server its new IP each time each changed. I don't know anything about particular clients to use because I'm using the one built-in in my home router.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and my IP address starts with 41. If I am not behind a NAT should the IP address that used work? How do I get my IP address "within the Internet"? Should I use DynDNS to accomplish this?

Comment: @Johan, if it starts with 41, then you are probably directly connected to the Internet. Did you compare the address returned by "ipconfig" to whatever whatismyip.com says? If they are the same, then you're definitely safe. You should use this address at the client side to connect. If you have firewall software, you may have to disable it or configure to open the port used. DynDNS is not used to obtain IP addresses, it just registers a name for you, and a DynDNS client updates this name to point to your IP address each time it changes.

Comment: @Sergey, yes they are the same. I'll try a few other options, it could be the firewall or something like that.

Comment: @Johan, what error are you getting anyway when trying to connect?

Comment: @Sergey. After a few seconds a get an IOException on the client side. I edited my original question, if you don't mind, can you take a look at that and let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: @Johan, what does the IOException say? Connection timed out, rejected, etc.? I've seen your edited question, but I have never tried something like that, so I can't give you any good advice here. It is certainly possible, but I don't know if it can be done for free and also how reliable and secure it would be, not to mention other possible problems we have no idea of.

Comment: The message that I get is: "The operation timed out", not very helpful.

Comment: @Johan, quite helpful in fact. It means that the client didn't get any reply, positive or negative. Could be because of a firewall or because of some network misconfiguration. Did you try to ping the server from the client?

Comment: I'll try to ping the server, but it also seems to me that it is some sort of network setup error.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write networking code for this, unless it really floats your boat. Take a look at SCP. http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/scp.html. There is a windows implementation where you can download putty (windows ssh client), and it is on most linux distributions. Alternatively, you could set up an FTP or SSH server on one or both of the machines.

"a fixed name for my computer that I can use instead of entering the IP address" would be a domain name, these are purchasable online for a few bucks.

Comment: @Orbit: the OP states that he want to *"transfer data (mostly simple commands)"* while *scp* is meant to copy files.  I'm not sure this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, but trying anyway without knowing what exactly he wants.

Comment: His socket code already works so this question is more a matter of configuration rather than programming.

Comment: There's a difference between what the OP thinks he wants and what he needs: In this case I think that the OP needs to figure out the vagaries of TCP/IP on the internet. He's already got his stuff working at home (LAN) and he's trying to move it to the public internet (WAN.) Johan really needs to understand what all needs to happen to enable such a move.

Comment: True this, I should have just ignored the last question within the question.

Comment: I want to use it in a existing security program at home that I created. I want to be able to connect remotely to the program and then monitor and control certain aspects of the program.

Comment: @Orbit: Yes, it is a Java program