# How to use SQL server from a different network

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL server running in my home, and everything in the same network works fine.

I would like for my computer at home to be running the SQL Server, and with a VB.NET application connect to it from school.

Is there any way? Thank you.

Comment: do a quick google search: "enable remote sqlserver" there are alot of good resources there. Basically, enable the seq server to allow remote connections, enable the tcp/ip, enable the firewall, port forward from your pc to your modem and copy your use the ip-address in the connection string instead of your pc name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send data between two computers over the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127687/how-do-i-send-data-between-two-computers-over-the-internet)

Comment: everything Keith said, plus set a _really_ strong password. You might also want to see if it's possible to restrict sysadmin (`sa` account) logins just to your home network.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to publish you home comp to the Internet real IP. so you need real IP address from your provider with port map 1433 to your home computer. don't forget to create strong password for sa account. 
also you need access from school to internet with SQL proto. In many cases in public networks only http/https is enabled.

Comment: if I create a VPN from home and use it at school, will this work? (it's just because I will only use this program once out of home).